# Using a function in a class to change the value of a variable in another class c++

Tags: c++

Is it possible to Use a function in a class to change the value of a variable in another class c++. I want to use the manger class to change the price in a events class or the price in the function.

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cstdio>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

class Manager {
public:
    void Changevalue() {
        //Changes the value of a variable some where in events class.
    }
};

class Event {
    //variable
    void price() {
        int price;
    }
};

int main() {
    Manager a;
    Event b;
    a.Changevalue();// use to change the value of a variable in the events class

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You should try to avoid this kind of relationship.  A class's data should be a discrete unit and shouldn't be changed externally.  Coupling is bad.

Comment: If you have to do it in the Event class declare Manager as a friend.

Comment: In fact the function `price()` looks altogether quite useless--no input, no output, not even a side effect, and the compiler will probably optimize that "variable" out of existence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am making a few assumptions about what you are trying to do based on the current structure of your code. For example, I assume that you want to set variables of objects, and not of classes, because you declared objects.

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cstdio>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

class Event {
    int price;
    public:
    void setPrice(int p) {
        price = p;
    }
};

class Manager {
    Event *event;
    public:
    Manager(Event * e) : event(e) {}
    void ChangeValue() {
        //Changes the value of a variable some where in events class.
        event->setPrice(5);
    }
};


int main() {
    Event b;
    Manager a(&b);
    a.ChangeValue();// use to change the value of a variable in the events class

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes.

1. If the variable in `Event` class is `public static`, you can directly access it

   ```
   void Changevalue()
   {
     Event::someVar = someValue; 
   }
   ```
2. If it is not `static` but `public`, you will need an object of `Event` of which you change the value

   ```
   void Changevalue(Event& evt)
   {
     evt.someVar = someValue;
   }
   ```
3. If it is neither `static` nor `public`, you will need an object of `Event` and a `public` method in `Event`  through which you change the value

   ```
   void Changevalue(Event& evt)
   {
     evt.ChangeSomeValue( someValue); //this is the best approach in OOP world
   }
   ```

Where `Event` class will be like

```
class Event {

  pulbic:
     void ChangeSomeValue( someType someValue);
  //other code
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add class Manager as a friend class of the class event.
Just add a member to class event:

```
class Event
{
public:
  friend class Manager;
  int price;
  void price()
  {

  }
```

But the price should be a member of class event too, or you can not change the value of a variable in a function. Because it's a local variable.

Answer (score 0):

You can likely pass the Event to the ChangeValue function as an argument.  You could then use any getter or setter methods the class provides.

Answer (score 0):

Have `Manager` take `Event` as an argument:

```
Event e;
Manager m(e);
```

Then, add a member function on `Event` that `Manager` can call to change its value.

Answer (score 0):

Q: Is it possible to Use a function in a class to change the value of a variable in another class?

A: Sure.  There are lots of ways.  For example:

1) You can simply make "price" a public member of "Event" - so anybody can change it, at any time.  This is usually Bad...

2) You can make Manager.ChangeValue() a friend of Event:

http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/friends.html

3) Or, arguably best, you can create a getter/setter method in "Event"

CAVEAT:

```
// Questionable
class Event {
public:
    void price() {
        int myPrice;  // The scope of this variable exists *ONLY INSIDE THE FUNCTION*
    }
};

// Better
class Event
private:
  int price;
public:
  int getPrice() { return price; }
  void setPrice (int p) { price = p; }
```